# how to break cell in excel using FileSaver library in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

```
 this.exportAsExcelFile(this.result, 'Report');
 // this.result: it is json object
 // 'Report': file name
```

I have | (pipe) seperated string. It prints in one line [see image for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10BKL.png)

Comment: You could try the Javascript newline character, `\n`

Comment: Yes i tried with \n and also \r\n but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got answer.
string should be like this:

```
str = "line1 \r\n line2 \r\n line3";
```

this string is in column E and row 2 thats why i have wrote it like

```
this.wrapAndCenterCell(worksheet['E2']);
```

see below function:

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
 const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
 this.wrapAndCenterCell(worksheet['E2']); //
 const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook ={Sheets:{'data':worksheet},SheetNames:
 ['data'] };
 const excelBuffer: any = XLSXStyle.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', 
 type: 
 'buffer' });
 this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName); 
}
```